# 'classif.ranger' not found in DictionaryLearner

Tags: random-forest, mlr3, r-ranger

I am trying to implement the tuning space 'classif.ranger.rbv1' from `mlr3tuningspaces`

However, I am getting an error for the learner that the 'classif.ranger' is not found in the DictionaryLearner

I have tried two methods, shown below

```
tuning_space <- lts("classif.ranger.rbv1")
learner <- tuning_space$get_learner()
```

and

```
tuning_space <- lts("classif.ranger.rbv1")
learner <- lts(lrn("classif.ranger"))
```

and both lead to the error message

```
Error: Element with key 'classif.ranger' not found in DictionaryLearner!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load `mlr3learners` first.

One way import the central mlr3 packages is to include a:

```r
library(mlr3verse)
```

at the top of your script.